# Access element directive children

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing a `navigation` directive that should have `a` elements for each nav item:

```
<navigation title="My Web Page">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</navigation>
```

How Can I get access to those anchors? Accessing the `element`'s children in `link()` only returns the template's children, not the 'a''s that I'm looking for.

```
.directive('navigation', function () {
    return {
      template: template,
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        // This only looks in the directive's template
        console.log($(element).find('a'));            
      }
    };
  });
```

What am I missing? I'm looking forward to attatch an array of the anchors in the directive's scope and iterate trough them within the template.

Comment: It appears you have forgotten to transclude the data in your directive and simply replacing the navigation tag with your template. Hence they are not found in your link function.

Comment: ngTransclude is what I was looking for! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move the original content within the new template you need to use the `transclude` property. When translude is set to true the directive will delete the original content but also make it available for reinsertion within your template through the `ng-translude` directive. See example below.

Without transluding the orginal data the anchor tags are removed and that is why your link function cannot find them.

```
.directive('navigation', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div>Tansclude data here: <span ng-translude></span></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log($(element).find('a'));            
        }
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused where your nav-tems are coming from, but I'll give it a go

I'm assuming your nav elements are defined in a controller that is parent to the directive

```
function myCtrl ($scope){
    $scope.navArray=[{title: 'Link1', href: 'www.example.com'}, {...}];
}
```

you would them have to declare the array as an attribute in your directive

```
<navigation nav="navArray"></navigation>
```

and two-way-bind it to the scope of your directive

```
.directive('navigation', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div><a ng-repeat="link in nav" href="link.href">{{link.title}}</a></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      scope: {
        nav: '='
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  });
```

Remember, you want to stay away from DOM manipulation in your link function. Instead, I recommend using ng-repeat in your template, and make sure the array of nav items is passed to your directive's scope.

Edit: See Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/8YQPh/3/